In general: How to calculate effective mass from a bandstructure?
How to calculate the effective mass of silicon for the two cases: valence band maximum and valence band minimum (both at gamma point)? Any general procedure would be great to see.

Is this for a calculation? Because if it's experimental, it might be better to post this in the Physics or Chemistry SEs—chances are you're more likely to get an answer there.

It's for the general procedure to calculate it from an available bandstructure. For example, any workflow from silicon band structure would also work well. @isolatedmatrix


"conduction" band minimum, not valence band minimum.


For my case, I would like to check it for valence band minimum as well. @Sha

Mathematically speaking, calculating the effective mass corresponds to fitting a parabola $E(k)=a + bk^2$ to the electronic energy dispersion $E(k)$ of the band in question. Here, $a$ is the energy of the extremum at $k=0$ (band edge) and $b=\frac{\hbar^2}{2m^*}$. The resulting effective mass $m^*$ is then typically expressed in units of the free electron mass, e.g. $m^*=0.3m_e$.
If you don't want to code it yourself, have a look at the Effmass package.
